# Youtube Addon needs two logins/apps to be activated

Tags: kodi, osmc, youtube

I used the Youtube Addon (v.5.3.6) for a long time without problems.
It's running on my Raspberry Pi 3 with OSMC + Kodi 17. But now there is always a strange error, I should Sign in again for two times but then the app "crashs".

Excerpt from the log files:

```
12:32:14.200 T:1253045232  NOTICE: Previous line repeats 1 times.
12:32:14.200 T:1253045232   ERROR: EXCEPTION Thrown (PythonToCppException) : -->Python callback/script returned the following error<--
                                         - NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
                                        Error Type: <class 'urllib2.URLError'>
                                        Error Contents: <urlopen error [Errno 0] Error>
                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/default.py", line 7, in <module>
                                            runner.run(__provider__)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/runner.py", line 32, in run
                                            __RUNNER__.run(provider, context)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/impl/xbmc/xbmc_runner.py", line 23, in run
                                            results = provider.navigate(context)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/abstract_provider.py", line 93, in navigate
                                            result = method(context, re_match)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/register_provider_path.py", line 12, in wrapper
                                            return func(*args, **kwargs)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/provider.py", line 426, in _on_sign
                                            yt_login.process(mode, self, context, re_match, context.get_settings().requires_dual_login())
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/helper/yt_login.py", line 88, in process
                                            access_token_tv, expires_in_tv, refresh_token_tv = _do_login(_for_tv=True)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/helper/yt_login.py", line 11, in _do_login
                                            json_data = _client.generate_user_code_tv()
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/client/login_client.py", line 172, in generate_user_code_tv
                                            return self.generate_user_code(client_id=client_id)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/youtube/client/login_client.py", line 196, in generate_user_code
                                            result = requests.post(url, data=post_data, headers=headers, verify=False)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/simple_requests/api.py", line 194, in post
                                            return _request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
                                          File "/home/osmc/.kodi/addons/plugin.video.youtube/resources/lib/kodion/simple_requests/api.py", line 165, in _request
                                            response = opener.open(request)
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
                                            response = self._open(req, data)
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
                                            '_open', req)
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
                                            result = func(*args)
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
                                            context=self._context)
                                          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
                                            raise URLError(err)
                                        URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 0] Error>
                                        -->End of Python script error report<--
12:32:14.350 T:1958224816   ERROR: GetDirectory - Error getting plugin://plugin.video.youtube/sign/in/
12:32:14.351 T:1958224816   ERROR: CGUIMediaWindow::GetDirectory(plugin://plugin.video.youtube/sign/in/) failed
12:32:15.391 T:1253045232  NOTICE: [plugin.video.youtube] Running: YouTube (5.3.8) on Krypton (Kodi-17.0) with Python 2.7.9
12:32:16.457 T:1286599664   ERROR: Unable to find plugin
12:32:16.458 T:1958224816   ERROR: GetDirectory - Error getting plugin://
12:32:16.458 T:1958224816   ERROR: CGUIMediaWindow::GetDirectory(plugin://) failed
```

Any ideas why it could not find the plugin overnight? Nothing changed.

**UPDATE:**
In the logs there's a notice, that I'm using Youtube v.5.3.8, in the addon v.5.3.6 is displayed.

Comment: Have you tried, reinstalling it, the problem is clearly a memory leak that's taking up all of the pis ram, it is likely a problem with the code base but may also be one with installation and/or the updating of used modules

Comment: Yeah I deinstalled it complete with all configs I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instruction of a closed [ticket](https://github.com/jdf76/plugin.video.youtube/issues/14) on the youtube addon git repository regarding Ubuntu I did this on my Raspi3 with OSMC:

```
sudo pip uninstall pyOpenSSL
```

After uninstalling pyOpenSSL I cleared the settings of the addon and I signed in again two times. Now the addon is working again.